# Android/Java: Failure to execute jar sample application from LeadBolt

Tags: android, executable, leadbolt

So I downloaded an example sample app from a company that makes android advertisement libraries. When I try and run it either from windows explorer or from the command console it fails. The console tells me that its missing a manifest, which it does NOT since I opened the jar in winrar and it does have a manifest file. Under Meta-IMF. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to use a sample jar for android development and I'm falling too short of understanding even how I can fix this. Whats up?

Comment: What do you mean by "try and run it from Windows Explorer..."? You can't "run" an Android .jar library from Win Explorer AFAIK.

Comment: By running it windows explorer, I thought I could just select and execute the file by browsing the folder that its in outside of the console. However, I did try and use the command console to launch it but that wasn't fruitful.

Comment: As Ugo said, if it's an Android application, you have to install it into an Android device or an emulator. You can't just run it on Windows. Also it is helpful to say which application and from where and not just "an app from a company"

Comment: But I'm trying to use the external library for the application then. I can set up a emulator for the program no worries, but I cant seem to use the methods and such from the library that I downloaded.